# Exchange server addon/plugin development

Tags: exchange-server

I want to create Addon for exchange server. Does Exchange server provides any SDK for that. If anybody knows about it please let me know.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

This link should give you an overview of what's available. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn820100.aspx